# Scaling a diamond shape

Tags: html, css

I’m making a diamond shape for a user’s image with the help of this [CodePen demo](http://codepen.io/4dgaurav/pen/KDbBe/).

But when I change the `width` and `height` according to my content the shape will disturb: see [my JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ytz5wjv1/).

In the selector `.losange, .losange div` the original values for `width` and `height` are both `250px` and in `.losange .los1` they’re both `355px`.

Here is my code:

```css
.losange, .losange div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 130px; /* originally 250px */
  height: 130px; /* originally 250px */
}

.losange {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(10px);
}

.losange .los1 {
  width: 130px; /* originally 355px */
  height: 130px; /* originally 355px */
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-74px);
}

.losange .los1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please, make a jsfiddle or code snippet

Comment: Updated my code with my code example. You can use above link

Comment: I am changing width and height of .losange, .losange div and .losange .los1 from original example,

Comment: I tried to change values, but I do not see any image rotating, even tried resizing the browser width, nothing happens...

Comment: Did you see http://jsfiddle.net/ytz5wjv1/  ?? and compare with this http://codepen.io/4dgaurav/pen/KDbBe/   (this is original example)

Answer (score 3):

You need to calculate right translate values:

```css
.losange, .losange div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 92px;
    height: 92px;
}
.losange {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translateY(10px) translateX(10px);
}
.losange .los1 {
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-27px);
}
.losange .los1 img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="losange">
    <div class="los1">
        <img src="http://photos-d.ak.instagram.com/hphotos-ak-xpa1/10483342_1471091656483347_532843009_n.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
Changed sizes - now Losange width is 130 pixels.

Comment: Yes, I m new for transform and translate properties value. In your code you take a different height width for image div and I want to make same height and width(130) Can you tell me how to calculate translate value?

Comment: If you set the same widths for `losange` and `los1` you'll get an octogon. You need to set lager width for `los1` to fill the parent element and get "Losange polygon". If you need a certain width of "Losange" (form the left corner to the right corner) you must calculate width of parent element: `width = √(130² / 2) ≈ 92`. So if you set this width you'll get Losange with 130px of width.